# Is there any way to list directory contents using javascript on github pages?

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I want to load a lot of images from a directory into my webpage. Can I list the names of all the files in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the github API in javascript, then call it in-page i.e ajax to populate your web page. You can also do a lot more with this api:

[https://developer.github.com/v3/][1]